# MS access Joining multiples instances of a table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to make a report on a set of data I gathered for a mining company.

Each day, a mining project will send data from their mine and mill. The data is made up of 3 sets of readings: what they produced, what they planned for that day, and what's the monthly target. Monthly target stays the same for the month, daily target is usually constant for the month but can change in special circumstances.

So I made a readings table for milling and mining and I combine 3 instances into the mining/milling report.

Here is the relationships graph of my database:

[image: relationships]

Now I want to calculate the percentage obtained for each reading. So I need to take the production readings and divide them by their equivalent daily target.

Problem is, I'm pretty much a noob at SQL and Access

I'm still at the point of trying to join the 3 readings tables for mining/milling of a single report.
I've tried this:

```
SELECT Rapport_quotidien.ID_rapport,
       Données_mine.*,
       Données_mine_1.*,
       Données_mine_2.*,
       Données_moulin.*,
       Données_moulin_1.*,
       Données_moulin_2.*
FROM Données_mine AS Données_mine_1,
     Données_mine AS Données_mine_2,
     Données_moulin AS Données_moulin_1,
     Données_moulin AS Données_moulin_2, (Données_moulin
INNER JOIN Rapport_moulin ON (Données_moulin.ID_data_moulin = Rapport_moulin.Cible_quotidienne)
      AND (Données_moulin.ID_data_moulin = Rapport_moulin.Usinage)
      AND (Données_moulin.ID_data_moulin = Rapport_moulin.Cible_mensuelle))
INNER JOIN ((Données_mine
INNER JOIN Rapport_minier 
        ON (Données_mine.ID_data_mine = Rapport_minier.Production)
       AND (Données_mine.ID_data_mine = Rapport_minier.cible_quotidienne)
       AND (Données_mine.ID_data_mine = Rapport_minier.cible_mensuelle))
INNER JOIN Rapport_quotidien ON Rapport_minier.ID_minier = Rapport_quotidien.Minier) 
        ON Rapport_moulin.ID_moulin = Rapport_quotidien.Moulin
WHERE (((Rapport_quotidien.ID_rapport)=[ID du rapport:]));
```

It gives me the corrects fields, but no data even though I have data to test on.
Here's what it looks like in design mode: [design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QHI2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, all I had to do was redefine the Join relations in the GUI. I linked Rapport_minier.cible_quotidienne to Données_mine_1, Rapport_minier.cible_mensuelle to Données_mine_2, Rapport_moulin.cible_quotidienne to Données_moulin_1 and Rapport_moulin.cible_mensuelle to Données_moulin_2.

[Solved query in GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPVRC.png)

Which gives this horrible mess of a query:

```
SELECT Rapport_quotidien.ID_rapport, Données_mine.*, Données_mine_1.*, Données_mine_2.*, Données_moulin.*, Données_moulin_1.*, Données_moulin_2.*
FROM Données_moulin AS Données_moulin_2 
INNER JOIN (Données_moulin AS Données_moulin_1 
INNER JOIN (Données_moulin 
INNER JOIN (Rapport_moulin 
INNER JOIN ((Données_mine AS Données_mine_2 
INNER JOIN (Données_mine AS Données_mine_1 
INNER JOIN (Données_mine 
INNER JOIN Rapport_minier ON Données_mine.ID_data_mine = Rapport_minier.Production) 
ON Données_mine_1.ID_data_mine = Rapport_minier.cible_quotidienne) 
ON Données_mine_2.ID_data_mine = Rapport_minier.cible_mensuelle) 
INNER JOIN Rapport_quotidien ON Rapport_minier.ID_minier = Rapport_quotidien.Minier) 
ON Rapport_moulin.ID_moulin = Rapport_quotidien.Moulin) 
ON Données_moulin.ID_data_moulin = Rapport_moulin.Usinage) 
ON Données_moulin_1.ID_data_moulin = Rapport_moulin.Cible_quotidienne) 
ON Données_moulin_2.ID_data_moulin = Rapport_moulin.Cible_mensuelle
WHERE (((Rapport_quotidien.ID_rapport)=[Rapport à chercher]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this format:

```
FROM ((MyTable MyTable1
INNER JOIN MyTable MyTable2 ON [links between MyTable1 and MyTable2])
INNER JOIN MyTable MyTable3 ON [links between MyTable1 or MyTable2 and MyTable3])
INNER JOIN OtherTable ON [links between MyTable1 or MyTable2 or MyTable3 and OtherTable]
```

or this

```
FROM (((RootTable
INNER JOIN SubTable SubTable1 ON [links between RootTable and SubTable1])
INNER JOIN SubTable SubTable2 ON [links between RootTable and SubTable2])
INNER JOIN SubTable SubTable3 ON [links between RootTable and SubTable3])
INNER JOIN OtherTable ON [links between RootTable and OtherTable]
```

You will probably need for `OUTER` joins instead of `INNER ones`, in which case also be careful to account for missing records

Answer (score 0):

Consider starting from parent table downwards in query build. And because this query uses many tables, use MS Access' GUI Design where tables should be placed in careful order and check results with each step. Because you have join relationships adding tables automatically sets `INNER JOIN ON` clauses.

1. First, start with *Report_Quotidien*, the base source of all joins.
2. Then, add *Rapport_minier*. Check results.

   - Then, and one by one its *Données* tables. Check results.
3. Then, add *Rapport_moulin*. Check results.

   - Then, add one by one its *Données* tables. Check results.

If one of the check results yield zero records, then you identified which table causes the issue. My guess, is you might need `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` on all links due to records that do not entirely line up. Again, do this in GUI designer step by step.

---

An alternative approach is to build child, *Mine* and *Mill* queries (without the master *Report_Quotidien* table), then join those in a master query. Notice too the use of tables aliases to reduce length with long names:

```
SELECT mn.*, ml.*
FROM (Report_Quotidien r
LEFT JOIN MineQuery mn ON mn.ID_minier = r.Minier)
LEFT JOIN MillQuery ml ON ml.ID_moulin = r.Moulin
```

MineQuery *(let UI designer set link fields, but adjust joins to LEFT)*

```
SELECT mine.*, d.*. d1.*, d2.*
FROM ((Rapport_minier mine
LEFT JOIN Données_mine d    ON d.ID_data_mine = mine.cible_quotidienne)
LEFT JOIN Données_mine_1 d1 ON d1.ID_data_mine = mine.cible_mensuelle)
LEFT JOIN Données_mine_2 d2 ON d2.ID_data_mine = min.Production
```

MillQuery *(let UI designer set link fields, but adjust joins to LEFT)*

```
SELECT mill.*, d.*. d1.*, d2.*
FROM ((Rapport_moulin mill
LEFT JOIN Données_moulin d ON d.ID_data_moulin = mill.cible_mensuelle)
LEFT JOIN Données_moulin_1 ON d1.ID_data_moulin = mill.Cible_quotidienne)
LEFT JOIN Données_moulin_2 ON d2.ID_data_moulin = mill.Usinage
```